# Backbone Routes and Webservices Path

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, backbone.js

I have been building my own Backbone application with a java EE backend, I am getting confused with paths between Web services and backbone.

This is the example I have been follwoing:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/using-backbone-js-with-a-restful-java-back-end/

So my understanding of this code is that when the url `wines:id`is called the before function loads the complete list of wines and then uses the `get()` method to find the item you were looking for.

**1.** If this is so why have the `findById` in the web resource as its never even used?

**2.** If I had a vast array of wines this seems a strange way of doing it, So how could I use the `findByName` function in the `wineresource` in backbone to create a collection of only the required items?

**3.** If the route says `wines:id` a backbone function is called but dose this also activate the web service path at `/wines/{id}` aswell?

Or do I have a complete mis-understanding of this code?

I come from a Java back round and am only being to understand backbone.

**EDIT**

**My Best Guess at answering Question two:**

If I wanted to go about selecting only certain wines by using the `findByName` would I have to create a new model and collection with with `urlRoot: "api/wines/:id"`?

**EDIT TWO**

For my solution above, the **ID** is a variable, How do setup the url to take variables and how do I properly call the model passing the desired value of **ID** ?

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    console.log('Closing view ' + this);
    if (this.beforeClose) {
        this.beforeClose();
    }
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
};

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        $('#header').html( new HeaderView().render().el );
    },

    routes: {
        ""          : "list",
        "wines/new" : "newWine",
        "wines/:id" : "wineDetails"
    },

    list: function() {
        this.before();
    },

    wineDetails: function(id) {
        this.before(function() {
            var wine = app.wineList.get(id);
            app.showView( '#content', new WineView({model: wine}) );
        });
    },

    newWine: function() {
        this.before(function() {
            app.showView( '#content', new WineView({model: new Wine()}) );
        });
    },

    showView: function(selector, view) {
        if (this.currentView)
            this.currentView.close();
        $(selector).html(view.render().el);
        this.currentView = view;
        return view;
    },

    before: function(callback) {
        if (this.wineList) {
            if (callback) callback();
        } else {
            this.wineList = new WineCollection();
            this.wineList.fetch({success: function() {
               $('#sidebar').html( new WineListView({model: app.wineList}).render().el );
               if (callback) callback();
            }});
        }
    }

});

tpl.loadTemplates(['header', 'wine-details', 'wine-list-item'], function() {
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Here is the model:

```
window.Wine = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "api/wines",
    defaults: {
        "id": null,
        "name":  "",
        "grapes":  "",
        "country":  "USA",
        "region":  "California",
        "year":  "",
        "description":  "",
        "picture":  ""
      }
});

window.WineCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Wine,
    url: "api/wines"
});
```

And this is the WineResource service:

```
@Path("/wines")
public class WineResource {

    WineDAO dao = new WineDAO();

    @GET @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Wine findById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
        System.out.println("findById " + id);
        return dao.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));
    }

@GET @Path("search/{query}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public List<Wine> findByName(@PathParam("query") String query) {
    System.out.println("findByName: " + query);
    return dao.findByName(query);
}
```

Comment: Backbone routes use the # (hash) in the url bar so there is no conflict with any application URLs

Comment: @jgitter Oh thanks this helps a-lot. Any idea how i would go about doing Question 2 ?

Comment: Your "best guess" at question 2 looks right, or close to right.  Have you tried it? ...